# Image within inner array is not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, sorting

***Functionality:***

I have an array of main image in the main menu list and when an image in the list is clicked, a secondary image will be displayed.

***Issue:***

All main image will always have a secondary image displayed. However, there is one main image that has 2 secondary images displayed when clicked. At this point, when I click on the specific main image with 2 secondary images, the 2 secondary image files are not displayed, when checked on the console log, it returns a 404, which is strange.

Hence, what I am intending to achieve is:

When I click on image A, secondary image A will be displayed.
Secondly, when I clicked on the image that has 2 secondary images; say imageB, secondary Image B1 and B2 will be displayed at the same time.

***What I have done:***

at the secondary image array, I have set an inner array within the first array. and on each image click it is suppose to read the correct array index.

***Code:***

```js
var MainImageArray = ["http://lorempizza.com/380/240", "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/"];

var OfferArray = [
  ["http://lorempizza.com/380/240"],
  ["http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/sports/", "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/"]
];

//Append array of images to list container in alphabetical Order
var x = 0;
number = 0;
Photoframe = "";
PrintPhotoFrame = "";
var container = document.getElementById('list');
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

BrandNameArray.forEach(function(url, index, originalArray) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.id = "Logo-" + x;
  img.src = url;
  docFrag.appendChild(img);

  //Choose Brand with popUp
  var selectedOffer = OfferArray[index];
  console.log("ImgClickedindex" + index);
  img.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("ButtonAudio").play();
    for (i = 0; i < innerList; i++) {
      $('#BrandDescription').fadeIn({
        duration: slideDuration,
        queue: false
      });
      $("#Description").attr('src', selectedOffer).show();
      console.log("index: " + index);
      number = index;
      //Choose Photoframe from second image
      PhotoFrame = PhotoFrameArray[index];
      console.log("PhotoFrameArray[index]:" + index);
      //Choose borderImage in canvas drawing
      PrintPhotoFrame = PrintPhotoFrameArray[index];
      console.log("PrintPhotoFrameArray[index]:" + index);
    }
  };
  x++;
});
container.appendChild(docFrag);
```

```html
<div id="Vivo_ChooseBrand" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index=1; top:0px; left:0px;">

  <!--Container to display all alphabetically sorted images-->
  <div class="Container">
    <div id="list" class="innerScroll"></div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="BrandDescription" class="menu" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display:none; top:0px; left:0px; z-index=2;">

  <img id="Description" style="position:absolute; top:124px; left:534px; z-index=99;">
</div>
```

Hence, I would like to ask for help on how to solve this issue??  The issue is that I was able to display the other secondary images, but however when it comes to the dual secondary image it is refusing to show.

Please help. thanks

Comment: Try to provide a fiddle please.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki fiddle should beup